# How to create a new column in PySpark based on a dynamic condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to create a new column in PySpark Dataframe. However the condition to create this new column will be dynamic

example:

```
df = df.withColumn(
                'update_date',
                to_date(
                    substring(df['update_date_string'], -8, 8),
                    'MM-dd-yy',
                ),
            )
```

To be converted to

```
column_expression = "to_date(
                    substring(df['update_date_string'], -8, 8),
                    'MM-dd-yy',
                )"
df = df.withColumn(
                'update_date',
                expr(column_expression )
            )
```

The second code with expr() is not creating the new column.
Please suggest how this could be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *expr()* you need pass SQL expression, not python (Docs: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-expr-expression-function/). Try

```
column_expression = "to_date(
                    substring(update_date_string, -8, 8),
                    'MM-dd-yy')"
df = df.withColumn(
                'update_date',
                expr(column_expression )
            )
```